# Custom Function Linear Regression

Tags: r, python-3.x, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to implement the following "R" code in python:

```
fit = lm(log(y) ~ log(x1) + log(x2) + 
x3, data=data);
```

I know in sklearn, you can make a linear regression with multiple variables. However, I specifically want to make the formula above.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it is too broad... it is pretty clear exactly what I want and I gave example code in a different language.

Comment: So basically instead of just Y = B1X1 + B2X2... it's Y = log(X1)*B1 + log(X2)*B2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a log transformation to `x1` and `x2` and then run the linear regression:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

log_x1 = np.log(x1)
log_x2 = np.log(x2)

log_y = np.log( y)

log_model = LinearRegression().fit( np.c_[log_x1, log_x2, x3], log_y)
```

Comment: I just edited the code, I had forgotten to log transform `y` and to add the `x3` variable.